# Dealing with different tables in SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am new to SQL and still learning how to write queries.. I have a few questions about the codes I have written that mostly regard using left join/ inner join

Suppliers(sid: int, sname: VARCHAR(30), address: VARCHAR(50))

Parts(pid: int, pname: VARCHAR(30), color: VARCHAR(10))

Catalog(sid: int, pid: int, cost: double)

1. Find snames of suppliers who supply every black part.

   ```
   select s.sid, s.sname from Suppliers s, Parts p
      where p.color = 'black'
      having count(p.pid) = 15;
   ```

My question for this query is, would I need to have Suppliers anywhere in the where clause in order for it to find the suppliers who supply every black part?

2. List snames of all suppliers who supply any black part.

   ```
    select s.sname from Suppliers s 
         inner join Parts p
         on p.color = 'black';
   ```

This is also the same case, am I using inner join correctly or how should I utilize both tables in this question.

Also with these two questions, do i need to use catalog at all since that is what could relate both suppliers and parts together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need catalog for both queries since that's the common thing that connects your suppliers and products together.

I might be overthinking this. Here's my train of thought.

**Structure**

```
create table suppliers (sid int, sname text, address text);
create table parts (pid int, pname text, color text);
create table catalog (sid int, pid int, cost int);

insert into suppliers values (1, 'walmart', ''), (2, 'target', ''), (3, 'amazon', '');
insert into parts values (1, 'ball', 'black'), (2, 'ball', 'white'), (3, 'bat', 'black'), (4, 'bat', 'white');
insert into catalog (sid, pid) values (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2);
```

**Select all black parts**

```
select group_concat(pid) as gc from parts p where p.color = 'black';

gc
------
1,3
```

**Select all parts sold by suppliers that are black**

```
select c.sid, group_concat(c.pid) as gc
from catalog c inner join parts p on c.pid = p.pid and p.color = 'black'
group by c.sid;

sid   gc
----- ------
1     1,3
2     1
```

**Find suppliers who supply all black parts**

```
select s.sname
from (
    select c.sid, group_concat(c.pid) as gc
    from catalog c inner join parts p on c.pid = p.pid and p.color = 'black'
    group by c.sid
) a
inner join (
    select group_concat(pid) as gc
    from parts p where p.color = 'black'
) b on a.gc = b.gc
inner join suppliers s on a.sid = s.sid

sname
--------
walmart
```

Similar to the above, your 2nd query will have to change as well to something like this:

**2nd Query**

```
select distinct s.sname
from catalog c
inner join parts p on c.pid = p.pid and p.color = 'black'
inner join suppliers s on c.sid = s.sid

sname
--------
walmart
target
```

In the above query, we combine catalog with parts to get all the catalogs that have black parts. Then we combine the result with suppliers to get the name of suppliers. If a supplier supplies more than one black part, their information can appear more than one times. So, we use distinct to get distinct names.

Example: http://rextester.com/IDH97131

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your Catalog table, assuming correct data insertion, is the way to achieve what you are trying to query. There is nothing to join (or directly relate) Parts and Suppliers together without having Catalog.

Let's take the 2nd color query as one example: (The Suppliers table does not have a `color` column, so that column cannot be used to join)

```
SELECT s.name
  FROM Suppliers s
    INNER JOIN Catalog c ON s.sid = c.sid
    INNER JOIN Parts   p ON c.pid = p.pid
 WHERE p.color = 'black';
```

That should do it, but if not, append your table schemas to the question. You get this info by doing a `SHOW CREATE TABLE Catalog` and then copy/paste the output. Then do the same for the other 2 tables.